# PHP Script causing server errors

Tags: php

Below is a php Script, its not clean nor friendly more or less need a point in the direction why its crashing my server, Im trying to view my error logs on my server but its crashed and i cant access it now....my php skills are not that good... any help is appreciated:

```
  $checker = 0;
  function shuffleArray($myArray) {
  $value_count = array_count_values($myArray);

  $last_value = $myArray[count($myArray) - 1];
  unset($myArray[count($myArray) - 1]);
  $shuffle = array();
  $last = false;

  while (count($myArray) > 0) {
  $keys = array_keys($myArray);
  $i = round(rand(0, count($keys) - 1));
   while ($last === $myArray[$keys[$i]] ) {
    $i = round(rand(0, count($keys) - 1));
    echo "stuck";$checker++;
    if($checker>100){
        echo " Too many checks so die, and restart process ";
        exit;

    }
  }
  $shuffle[] = $myArray[$keys[$i]];
  $last = $myArray[$keys[$i]];
  unset($myArray[$keys[$i]]);
}

if ($last_value === $last) {
$i = 0;
foreach($shuffle as $key=>$value) {
     if ($value !== $last_value) {
        $i = $key;
        break;
    }
  }
  array_slice($shuffle, $i + 1, 0, $last_value);
  } else {
  $shuffle[] = $last_value;
  }

  return $shuffle;
  }

 $shuffleReel = (shuffleArray($virtualReel));
 function bob(){
if($checker>100){
    $checker = 0;
    shuffleArray();
    echo "bob";
    reset($myArray);
}
  }
```

Comment: Why can't you access your logs?

Comment: This is a mess... Can you please narrow it down before posting all of your PHP?

Comment: cant access my server because of memory issue, id say there error is occurring during the loop near the line"too many check and die" i dont think its dieing

Comment: i really dont understand why this question is voted down,

Comment: The `while` loop in shuffleArray is never going to terminate - it will run so long as there are values in `$myArray`, but none of the code inside the loop removes items from that array. You're getting an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no error handling in the loop, so whats happened is my server resources are all used up:
to fix this i had to return null to flash /Action script from where the script is fired.

```
       if($checker>100){
        $returnString = http_build_query("Error_1); // for flash to restart script
                     echo $returnString;
        exit;   
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

When accessing associative array variables in double quotes (called interpolation) you have to encase them in {}. For example:

`$reelFrame['value1'] = "{$ini_array['Symbol1']}";//notice I added {} around the array and encased Symbol1 in single quotes. The latter part is not necessary but recommended.`

You'll have to do that for all ten lines.

Comment: Alternatively you could just get rid of the double quotes around the array variable you're accessing :P

Comment: should have the reelframes in arrays anyway, not ten lines, at the moment all this is then read by actionscript so for now i leave this code as took me a while ...im not a php developer

Comment: I understand but you should still check it out because not having the curly braces around it may cause fatal errors depending on your server setup :)